# how do i commit and push my Sharekit 2.0 modified SHKConfig.h to my repo

Tags: git, sharekit

I've pulled Sharekit 2.0 as a submodule as instructed.  All works fine and I modfied the SHKConfig.h file with my app keys etc.  All works fine.

I need to source control the config with my project however.  How do I do this as its located within the Sharekit submodule and not my project repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply needed to sub class DefaultSHKConfigurator and override the properties

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your right: your currently have the Sharekit files in a different folder than your project and need to get those Sharekit files into your project folder?

Try this (after having backup your project by hand): in Xcode, delete the Sharekit files and folders - take care to not also delete the original files (Xcode will ask you about this).

Then: having the Xcode Project Navigator opened, drag the original Sharekit folder into your project (maybe into a subfolder called 3rg party). Xcode will ask, if the files should be copied, you answer yes. Run the project. Done. Should now work with your version control.